# Large numbers in PHP

Tags: php, numbers

I've been playing around with large numbers in PHP and was just wondering what module/process it uses to calculate the large numbers, and why it isn't used for all PHP numeric functions.

Hope this explains it a little better

My `PHP_INT_MAX` is 2147483647 (31 bits)

But, I figured out can create a 1017 bit number, by using:

```
$largenumber = pow(142,142);
```

This number is 310 digits long so I wont paste it in here ...

But then if I then try convert it to binary:

```
decbin($largenumber);
```

I get 1111111111111111111111111111111 (31 bits ... `PHP_INT_MAX`)

So, if the `pow()` function can handle this large number, why can't the `decbin()` function handle it?

Comment: If you need high precision for values that exceed that of 32-bit PHP, either switch to 64-bit PHP, or use [bcmath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) or [gmp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php)

Comment: Doing binary maths with fixed-size numbers is lighting fast (that's what computers are designed to do). Arbitrary precision libraries like bcmath or gmp operate on arbitrary size strings—there's probably no practical reason to make that the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official PHP documentation on [`pow`](http://www.php.net/pow):

> base raised to the power of exp. If both arguments are non-negative
> integers and the result can be represented as an integer, the result
> will be returned with integer type, otherwise it will be returned as a
> float.

```
$largenumber = pow(142,142);
var_dump($largenumber); //float(INF)
```

`pow` returns a `float`, which [`decbin`](https://www.php.net/decbin) tries to convert to an `int` and where you exceed the maximum integer value.